# Can XAMPP be used for a "real" server?

Tags: webserver, xampp

According to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP), XAMPP is merely a packaging of server software such as apache, PHP, SQL, etc, that can be run locally.

The question becomes: is it practical to use the same software on an actual server, but set a config file to automatically run `/opt/lampp/lampp start` on startup? Or is it better to just get the software and directly install it?

Not too savvy with networking, particularly on the server side, so any answers would be a great help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP works great on Windows. Heck, even for Linux, as it provides a consistent "packed" experience. Comes with everything, without the need to set up anything. Great for dev purpose, I suppose.

But on Ubuntu you can install LAMP pretty easily, and it's the "same thing", really.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

(Except you have to keep Lampp up-to-date by yourself, and Ubuntu provides patches / updates for their own LAMP stack.)

**Short version**: Stick to the Ubuntu LAMP.